# how to add items in decreasing order with a header linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue, comparator

If I have a header linked list that is supposed to be created in decreasing order how can I use comparator to add by comparing the current node and the new node?

Would I use priorityComparator.compare(e, temp.next.value)?

```
public boolean add (E e) {
  //front always points to the header.
  final ListNode<E> front = highest;
  ListNode<E> temp = front;

  ListNode<E> newNode = new ListNode<E>(e, null);

  //Insert to front if header points to null.
  if (temp.next == null){
      temp.next = newNode;
  }
  //how to add in sorted order?


return true;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using Java's standard [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/PriorityQueue.html)?

Comment: +1 for halex. Use PriorityQueue. By default it has natural order but you'll have to override the comparator to change it to decreasing order.